# GPU cores used for a specific task

Tags: python

I am new to cuda based programming. how to get number of GPU cores (CUDA)used for a program in python? can we set the core number for a specific task?

Comment: Python itself **does not** have access to GPU. So the answer depends on the specific lib you use.